# Unwanted spacing for cover block

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I am running into issues when using the cover block.

I created the following header with the cover block:

[image]

Unfortunately there is more space to the top when using the cover block which makes the header move upwards when navigating to another page.

[image]
[image]

I can move the header up with the following code:

```
position: relative;
top: -19.5px
```

This just doesn't seem right though. How can I fix the spacing issue?

Just to make clear, it's not the padding from the cover block:

[image]

I have no clue where this spacing is coming from:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is something that can be diagnosed from screenshots, there's no code in your question, blocks to reproduce the issue, or links to a site that can be used to inspect and reverse engineer where the space is coming from. Can you edit your question to fix that?

Comment: Tbh, I feel a bit dumb now. The only thing I had to change was the content position from center to top...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the content was centered and not aligned to the top of the cover:

[image]